# Change cells value assignment to range and array assignment to improve performance

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I am reviewing legacy VBA code to improve performance.

I want to change cells assignment to a range and array assignment.

How can I transform the cell references to a range?

```vb
Sheets("Model").Activate
YearRange = Range("C7:EZ7").value

loopvar = 1
Do While YearRange(1, loopvar) <> "" And Right(Trim(YearRange(1, loopvar)), 1) <> "E"
    strValue = Trim(YearRange(1, loopvar))
    Year = CInt(strValue)
  
    GetSpecificData Year, RptPe, RptAvg
  
    If (RptPe <> 0) Then Cells(508, loopvar + 2).value = RptPe
    If (RptAvg <> 0) Then Cells(509, loopvar + 2).value = RptAvg

    loopvar = loopvar + 1
Loop
```

The cells assignment are about 15. I put two for reference. Usually there are 30 or more years, so running this piece of code usually takes about 20 or more seconds.

I had a similar loop in another place, but instead of cells used range, and I was able to create a array and then assign the array to the range and reduce the times to less than one second.

`GetSpecificData` gets the data from a year and populates the variables with the data, the time it takes to do this is negligible.
The bottleneck seems to be the assignment of the data to the cell.

Comment: What happens in `GetSpecificData()`?

Comment: get specific data, gets the data from a database and fills the variables with the data

Comment: To clarify, you're querying during every loop?

Comment: not exactly it does have many methods and techniques implemented to reduce the times, we have timed the different parts and this call makes up less thatn 10% of the total time

Comment: Without showing the function, to see the whole picture, it is difficult to be helped.

Comment: And what the question title should mean, please? What `Range` are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say what might be cause with so limited information.

But what may be the culprit is the automatic recalculation in XL? Your sheet now recalculates the entire sheet after each `Cells(508, loopvar + 2).value = RptPe` this may likely be the cause for slow execution.

Maybe you could decorate the `While ... Loop` with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` like below. Though ensure some errorhandling as otherwise your application get's 'stuck' in a non-calculating mode if an error occurs or the code breaks.

```
Sub Something()
    On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual        

    Sheets("Model").Activate
    YearRange = Range("C7:EZ7").Value

    loopvar = 1
    Do While YearRange(1, loopvar) <> "" And Right(Trim(YearRange(1, loopvar)), 1) <> "E"
        strValue = Trim(YearRange(1, loopvar))
        Year = CInt(strValue)
    
        GetSpecificData Year, RptPe, RptAvg
        
        If (RptPe <> 0) Then Cells(508, loopvar + 2).Value = RptPe
        If (RptAvg <> 0) Then Cells(509, loopvar + 2).Value = RptAvg
      
        loopvar = loopvar + 1
    Loop
    
ErrorExit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```